# Generic parameter in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, where-clause, array-initialization

I have this classes:

```
interface Info{}

class AInfo : Info { }
class BInfo : Info { }

class SendInfo {
    static public f_WriteInfo(params Info[] _info) {

    }
}

class Test {
  static void Main() {
    SendInfo.f_WriteInfo( 
                        new[] { 
                            new AInfo(){ ... },
                            new BInfo(){ ... },
                       } );
// This will generate an error. 
// There will be need casting between new and [] like new Info[]
  }
}
```

Is there any way to do this without casting?

Like:

```
class SendInfo {
    static public f_WriteInfo(params T _info) where T : Info {
```

Comment: What is wrong with `new Info[]`? It isn't casting. And technically you don't need an array, you can provide comma-delimited arguments when using `params`: `WriteInfo(info1, info2);`

Comment: As an aside, the `params` keyword means you don't have to explicitly create an array when calling the method, you can just do `MyMethod(firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam);`

Comment: the problem is that `new[]` is interpreted as `object[]`, in this context

Comment: Also note that your provided code should look something like: `params Info[] infos`, note the array syntax around the parameter when using `params`.

Comment: @RonKlein: No, `new[]` won't compile at all in this case. The array type *has* to be the type of one of the expressions.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I'll take a deeper look, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Also note that there is no generic code in this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set your method signature to be:

```
static public f_WriteInfo(params Info[] _info) {}
```

and call it like:

```
SendInfo.f_WriteInfo(new AInfo(){ ... }, new BInfo(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 4):

this works fine

```
interface Info { }

class AInfo : Info { }
class BInfo : Info { }

class SendInfo
{
    public static void f_WriteInfo(params Info[] _info)
    {
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        SendInfo.f_WriteInfo(new AInfo(), new BInfo());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    interface Info{}

public class AInfo : Info
{
    public AInfo(){}
}
public class BInfo : Info { }

class SendInfo {
    public static void f_WriteInfo(params Info[] _info) {

    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SendInfo.f_WriteInfo( 
                    new Info[] { 
                        new AInfo(),
                        new BInfo()
                   } );
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't want to cast with `Info`. I mean that want to use like `new[] { new AInfo(), new BInfo() }`. To do this can I add `where` expression to somewhere?

Comment: Then SendInfo.f_WriteInfo(new AInfo(){ ... }, new BInfo(){ ... }); is best

Comment: @DaveS this definitely works, this is what the compiler translates your solution into.

Comment: @uzay95 whilst the other answers are better as they're easier to read, they will all compile to exactly the same. There's no casting involved.

Comment: @GrahamClark; Apologies. You are correct about the compiler logic however I never knew you could invoke in this way. I've removed my initial comment.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> The params keyword lets you specify a method parameter that takes a variable number of arguments. You can send a comma-separated list of arguments of the type specified in the parameter declaration, or an array of arguments of the specified type. You also can send no arguments.

So you don't need to write `new []` before arguments.

I guess the link below will also be useful 
[how-to-pass-a-single-object-to-a-params-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350/how-to-pass-a-single-object-to-a-params-object)