# Unpacking an array into method arguments

Tags: c#, arrays, syntax, variadic-functions, params-keyword

As you know C# supports variadic methods through the `params` keyword:

```
int Add(params int[] xs) {
    return xs.Sum();
}
```

Which can then be called with any number of arguments you like:

```
Add(1);
Add(1, 2);
Add(1, 2, 3);
```

But say I want to call `Add` using an array of `int`s<sup>1</sup>. Is this possible and how (preferably without reflection)? I tried the following but they gave syntax errors (the syntax was pure guessing):

```
var xs = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Add(xs...); // doesn't work; syntax error
Add(params xs); // doesn't work; syntax error
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> My actual use-case is different but I thought this example would be less complicated.</sup>

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: @Antonijn syntax error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350/how-to-pass-a-single-object-to-a-params-object
This thread is saying it should work. Could the simplification be hiding something?

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"?  Do you get a compile-time error, run-time error, or unexpected output?

Comment: You are returning something in a method that doesn't return anything (`void`)

Comment: Your example is invalid, because you can actualy invoke `Add` method with an array of `int`.

Comment: You defined your method `void` and do you want to return `int` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your method needs a return type:

```
int Add(params int[] xs) {
    return xs.Sum();
}
```

And to call it with an array you just use the ordinary syntax for method calls:

```
int[] xs = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var result = Add(xs);
```

Comment: What would happen if `Add` takes `object[]`? Any type is converible to `object`, so wouldn't that be ambiguous?

Comment: you actually need to cast the inner objects.
you could try var xsAsObjcet = xs.ToList.Cast<object>().ToArray;

Answer (score 2):

The `params` keyword basically just allows you to take advantage of a little syntactic sugar. It tells the compiler that when it sees

```
Add(1, 2, 3);
```

It should convert that to

```
Add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3});
```

So to do this from your code, you don't have to do anything special.

```
 int[] parameters = new int[] { ... }
 results = Add(parameters);
```

See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) for more details.

Comment: use `@params` for variable name which is a C# keyword. This won't compile

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can just call it with an array like you would a normal method:

```
Add(xs);
```

Nothing fancy, no `params` keyword on the method call, no dots.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] tmp =  {1, 2};
    var sum = Add(tmp);
}
public static int Add(params int[] xs)
{
    return xs.Sum();
}
```

Should work just fine..

Answer (score 0):

If it's anything like Java, you can just call the method with the array as an argument.

This feature is also what makes varargs dangerous, especially if one of the vararg types is also an array...