# Trouble with params and invoke handler

Tags: c#, invoke, parameters

I'm trying to call `Invoke` with a array as parameter.
The problem is that `Invoke` uses the `params` - if my array is 3 elements long, `Invoke` tries to call a method with 3 parameters *instead* of calling the method with one ARRAY parameter:

```
private void something(Control[] dataDropControls) {
   // ...
   this.Invoke(new Action<Control[]>(initControls), dataDropControls);
}

private void initControls(Control[] controls) {
    // ...
}
```

([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350/how-to-pass-a-single-object-to-a-params-object) does not answer my question, because the parameter array is build in the calling function. Im my case, the function gets the already built array.)

**Q: How can I call `Invoke` so that it can call the method with one array parameter?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Invoke` tries to call the delegate dynamically, you should be able to wrap the input array in another

```
private void Invoke(Action<Control[]> act, Control[] elements)
{
    act.DynamicInvoke(new object[] { elements });
}
```

This issue is caused by array covariance, since you can do

```
Control[] elements = ...
object[] arr = elements;
```

so the input `Control[]` can be passed directly to `Invoke`, which results in each array elements being passed separately to the method.