# Pass array of string to xunit test method

Tags: arrays, xunit, xunit.net

I want to pass an array of string to one of my XUnit test method, but when I just do the following it doesn't work (array + params mechanism)

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData(new object[] { "2000-01-02", "2000-02-01" })]
public void TestSynchronizeMissionStaffing_PeriodNoMatch(string[] dateStrings)
```

I can work around the issue like this:

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData(0, new object[] { "2000-01-02", "2000-02-01" })]
public void TestSynchronizeMissionStaffing_PeriodNoMatch(int dummy, string[] dateStrings)
```

But I'm hoping there something better to resolve the issue.

Can you tell me?

Comment: The number of string inside the array could be anything.

Comment: it's 2018 and still this is the only workaround that's worked for me. Should really open an issure for xUnit

Comment: fix that last comment to WAS the only workaround. It appears there's actually [a straightforward solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48100749/978502)

Answer (score 77):

Use [`params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) before the method's `string[]` argument, and then you won't need to initialize a `string[]` in `InlineData` attribute, rather you could use a variable number of `string` literals, for which the compiler doesn't complain one bit:

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData("2000-01-02", "2000-02-01")]
public void TestSynchronizeMissionStaffing_PeriodNoMatch(params string[] dateStrings)
```

Comment: How I would pass an empty collection?

Comment: @renatogbp Using yair's  solution you just need to add another inline [InlineData()]. This creates an empty array upon the invocation of the test.

Answer (score 48):

For the benefit of searchers - in 2020, this is possible without `params` or `object` casting.

The key to getting it to play nicely seems to be to write the method signature before writing the `InlineData` parts. Here's some working code:

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData(true, "expected", new string[] { "expected", "another" })]
[InlineData(false, "nope!", new string[] { "expected", "another" })]
public async void StringCheck_WithInputs_ExpectResultsMatch(bool expectedResult, string expectedString, string[] possibleStrings)
{
    bool actualResult = false;

    foreach(var row in possibleStrings)
    {
        if(row == expectedString)
        {
            actualResult = true;
        }
    }

    Assert.Equal(expectedResult, actualResult);
}
```

Comment: Actually, when you have only one parameter (the array) it doesn't work, but when you have more parameters than one array, then it works just fine.

Comment: UPDATE (xunit 2.4.1 / xunit.runner.visualstudio 2.4.2): Now it's working just with the array parameter @Jacob

Comment: @MaiconHeck, what Jacob said appears to hold true still. I am using _xunit 2.4.1_ and _xunit.runner.visualstudio 2.4.3_ and visual studio complains unless I start the InlineData() attribute with some primitive argument.

Comment: Experimenting with this, the order of your parameters is important. Adding the string[] array last works, putting it first fails.

Comment: I'm not sure how people are making this work as putting "new string[]" results CS0182 (attribute argument must be a constant)

Comment: @MattM - They're making it work by putting a dummy attribute before it, e.g., `public void MyTest(int iLiterallyDoNotCare, string [] importantArray)` and `[InlineData(666, new string [] { "Puppies", "Kittens" })]`

Comment: This saved me so much confusion! I was wondering why it worked on one method and not the other.

Answer (score 8):

This should work

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(new object[] { new string[] { "2000-01-02", "2000-02-01" } })]
public void TestSynchronizeMissionStaffing_PeriodNoMatch(string[] dateStrings)
```

When u initialize an object array like you did all elements on it is a single object,  so when you trying to pass string array as parameter it passes a first element of the object array which is "2000-01-02".

Comment: This is the correct answer as you can read in this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/2060

Answer (score 5):

This is a C# params feature in which an array is expanded. so xunit fails to input it to your one argument, you can cast the array to force it, like this:

`[InlineData((object)(new object[] { "2000-01-02", "2000-02-01" }))]`

see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350/how-to-pass-a-single-object-to-a-params-object).

Comment: works for me... would you like to share a gist/repo?

Comment: I've attached a screenshot showing that the array is passed.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/af6fc4095705228909de923e25ac0645#gistcomment-1742472

Comment: I use VS studio 2015 community, Resharper 10.2, XUnit 2.1.0. Do you have a clue why we get beferent behaviour?

Comment: Haven't tried (yet) this env. some related issue: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/763 you might want to discuss over there. Thanks for the vote, please update if you find something

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ClassData` or `MemberData` attributes. These allow you to specify a method which returns the data you need

The method can be in a separate class (`ClassData`) or a method in the same class as the test (`MemberData`)

this explains it nicely
http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/25/xunit-theory-working-with-inlinedata-memberdata-classdata/

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a bug of XUnit. I've reported here:

https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/2456

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to pass a string array as argument to your Test, you can use your code, just add the "params" keyword to your string array prepended to it. It works just fine.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(new object[] { "2000-01-02", "2000-02-01" })]
public void TestSynchronizeMissionStaffing_PeriodNoMatch(params string[] dateStrings)
{
   //Assert.[YourVerifier]();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Xunit version `2.4.1` and with `ChrisCa`'s answer above. I was able to simply do this below, that way the data can be separated from the test(s).

```
public class NoGenTests
{
    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(NoGenTestsData.Nos), MemberType = typeof(NoGenTestsData))]
    public void NoGenTest(int size, int[] nos)

    {
         /*
        foreach (var item in nos)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Item is " + item);
        }*/
        Assert.Equal(size, nos.Length);
    }

}

public class NoGenTestsData
{

    public static object[] Nos =
    {
            new object[] {3, new int[] {2, 3, 5}},
            new object[] {6, new int[] {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}},
            new object[] {7, new int[] {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17}},
            new object[] {8, new int[] {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}},
            new object[] {2, new int[] {2, 3}},
            new object[] {1, new int[] {2}}
        };
}
```