# Pass Multiple Arrays to xUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I understand how to pass one array to xUnit: [Pass array of string to xunit test method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419534/pass-array-of-string-to-xunit-test-method)

However, I'm in a situation where I want to pass three arrays to my test method:

```
Type1[] ReturnValuesForMock;
Type2[] ExpectedTestResult;
Type3[] TestData
```

Is there any way to do this? `Type1` is an enum, so I can use a compile-time constant `new [] {enum}` but that doesn't work for `Type2` which needs a call to `new()`. I can then deal with `Type3` as `params`.

I feel like this really ought to be possible but I'm not sure how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but I've worked out that I can use the `[ClassData]` attribute on my tests like this:

```
    [Theory]
    [ClassData(typeof(TestDataGenerator))]
    public void Test1(Type1[] t1, Type2[] t2, Type3[] t3)
    {
        //MyTest
    }
```

And then provide the data through a `TestDataGenerator` class:

```
    private class TestDataGenerator:IEnumerable<object[]>
    {
        private static readonly List<object[]> _data = new()
        {
            new object[]{new Type1[] {...}, new Type2[]{...)}, new Type3[]{...}},
        ...
        };

        public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator() => _data.GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    }
```