# Having Object as params in a Function

Tags: javascript, function, object

I'd like to ask regarding an object as a param in a function. Could someone provide a simple sample of this?

I'm only familiar with the below:

```
function sampleFunction(par1, par2, par3){

   return par1 + par2 + par3;
  }
```

I would like to know how to use an object as a param in a function.

Cause I want to use 1-7 params. So to lessen this someone told me I can use objects as params but how?

thank you to those who will help

Comment: you are showing two different things.please make it nore clear

Comment: cannot understand what you want to ask

Comment: `but some one told me`, you can clarify with that person to know in depth more quickly.

Comment: he's too busy to ask. THat's why i'm here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a single object\[\] to a params object\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350/how-to-pass-a-single-object-to-a-params-object)

Comment: This link will help you more: [How to pass a single object[] to a params object[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350/how-to-pass-a-single-object-to-a-params-object)

Answer (score 1):

This is the original function. 3 arguments passed to the function.

```
function sampleFunction(par1, par2, par3){
    return par1 + par2 + par3;
}

sampleFunction(par1, par2, par3); // call function
```

You can pass the object to the function as the only argument. It gives you the same result.

```
var obj = {
    par1: par1,
    par2: par2,
    par3: par3
};

function sampleFunction(params){
    return params.par1 + params.par2 + params.par3;
}

sampleFunction(obj); // call function
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just have to define a variable previously (just to have a clear code), and send it as a parameter:

```
function previousFunction() {

   var args = {
     name: 'Yoda',
     option2: 'B'
   };

   someFunction(args);
}

function someFunction(args) {
   var name = args.name;
   var option2 = args.option2;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use args, for example:

```js
    function a({b ,c}) {
    console.log('b: ', b, 'c: ', c)
}
    
a({ b: 1, c: 2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an object as you said (which is a good practice):

```
function someFunction(obj) {
   console.log(obj.option1, obj.option2);
}
someFunction({ option1: true, option2: false });
```

Using es6 you could do:

```
function someFunction({ option1, option2 }) {
   console.log(option1, option2);
}
someFunction({ option1: true, option2: false });
```

If you pass them as params and capture them with the arguments clause:

```
function someFunction(option1, option2) {
     console.log(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
}
someFunction(true, false);
```

Take care that arguments is NOT an array, it is an array like object, you can access elements by index and it has a length property but it lacks the rest of array methods.