# How to pass single string to a method expects array of string

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to objective C. Usually in C# we can use params[] string as argument type when we want to send single or multiple strings to a method. Which we can either pass a single string or collection of strings without any data type issue. Do we have anything similar in objective C

Comment: I think, this link will helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350/how-to-pass-a-single-object-to-a-params-object

Answer (score 0):

All Objective-C reference type is a subclass of NSObject. This allow us some level of dynamic typing.

Below two versions are basically the same.

Old, generic version:

```
- (void)funcWithString:(id)param {
    NSLog(@"funcWithString %@", param);
}

- (void)funcWithStringArray:(NSArray*)paramArr {
    NSLog(@"funcWithStringArray %@", paramArr);
    for (id str in paramArr) {
        [self funcWithString:str];
    }
}
```

More modern, static version:

```
- (void)funcWithString:(NSString*)param {
    NSLog(@"funcWithString %@", param);
}

- (void)funcWithStringArray:(NSArray<NSString*>*)paramArr {
    NSLog(@"funcWithStringArray %@", paramArr);
    for (NSString* str in paramArr) {
        [self funcWithString:str];
    }
}
```

C# Object ~> Obj-C id
C# [] ~> Obj-C NSArray

Used like below (all 3 are equivalent):

```
[self funcWithString: @"single string"];  

[self funcWithStringArray: @[@"single string"]];  

[self funcWithStringArray: [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"single string"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In objective-c , if you are want to pass the single object where array of object is required, then you just have to declare the array with single object.

You cannot pass the single object where array is considered

In Objective-c Array is declared as simple

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"String1"];
```

Pass this array to function