# Unit Test won't run with array as last parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have two unit tests as follows:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("input1", new object[] { "input2" })]
public void Test1(string input1, object[] input2)
{

}

[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(new object[] { "input1" }, "input2")]
public void Test2(object[] input1, string input2)
{

}
```

The first unit test, `Test1`, won't run because `System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Object[]'.`. `Test2` (with the parameters switched) runs just fine. I think this might be because `Test1` is sensing `input2` as a sort of [`params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params). <s>As I am not specifying `params`, I am not sure how this could be the case.</s> ([it seems that `DataRowAttribute` specifies `params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datarowattribute.-ctor?view=mstest-net-1.2.0#Microsoft_VisualStudio_TestTools_UnitTesting_DataRowAttribute__ctor_System_Object_System_Object___)) What is a way in which I can get `Test1` to work (with the parameters in that order)?

As Jonathan suggested, I have tried the following with the same results:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("input1", (object)new object[] { (object)"input2" })]
public void Test1(string input1, object[] input2)
{

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a single object\[\] to a params object\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350/how-to-pass-a-single-object-to-a-params-object)

Comment: @JonathonChase please note my edit. I am not specifying `params` in the method so this is a different question (Additionally - the solution on the question you linked does not solve my problem)

Comment: It's not the method that has the `params`, it's the constructor of `DataRowAttribute` you are using. I would try just `[DataRow("input1", new [] {"input2"})]` or possible `[DataRow("input1", new object[] { new object[] { "input2" } })]`

Comment: Good to know. Please note my edit

Comment: Your first suggestion `new [] {"input2"}` causes build errors and while the second suggestion works, it seems quite ugly. Is there a better way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187069/discussion-between-derekantrican-and-jonathon-chase).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this post: [The mysterious ways of the params keyword in C#](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130806-00/?p=3603)

> Note that the language specification prefers normal form over expanded form: It considers expanded form only if normal form does not apply.

It seems that you basically have two options, if you want to stick with the `object` type:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("input1", new object[] { new object[]{ "input2" } })]
public void Test1(string input1, object[] input2)
{

}
```

or *(won't work, read edit below)*

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow("input1", "input2")]
public void Test1(string input1, object[] input2)
{

}
```

**Edit**: As pointed out by [derekantrican](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2246411/derekantrican), the `params` keyword is specified in the [DataRowAttribute constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.datarowattribute.-ctor?view=mstest-net-1.2.0#Microsoft_VisualStudio_TestTools_UnitTesting_DataRowAttribute__ctor_System_Object_System_Object___):

```
public DataRowAttribute (object data1, params object[] moreData);
```

This means that to use the `Test1` constructor as specified in the question, the `object[]` must be inside another `object[]` as in my first example, while the second example will not work, since a `string` won't match the signature of an `object[]`.

Comment: It seems that the second suggestion doesn't work so the first one seems to be my only option (although it's quite ugly IMO)

Comment: I absolutely agree! Also, I couldn't quite find an explanation as to why the implicit params keyword is even applied, but I tried creating a project including your code, and my IntelliSense suggested to remove the array creation since it's redundant when using the params keyword (which I didn't either), so it's definitely a thing.

Comment: So it looks like my options are either use your first suggestion or switch the method's parameter order. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The params keyword is not implicit. It is in the relevant constructor for `DataRowAttribute`: `public DataRowAttribute(object data1, params object[] moreData)`. Right click on that `DataRow(...)` attribute in your code in Visual Studio, and select "Go To Definition". @derekantrican

Comment: Ah! That explains why the latter example won't work, since ´"input2"´ doesn't fit into the object[] defined by the Test1 method. I'll edit the answer, thanks!