# Unit Test throws TargetParameterCountException when using params array

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I'm setting up unit tests using `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` test attributes. I'm trying to pass a different number of elements into a `params` array in my test method, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64826512/4320665).

Here's the relevant code in my `[TestClass]`:

```cs
[TestClass]
public class ExtensionsTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    [DataRow(1, "")]
    [DataRow(1, "stuff")]
    [DataRow(1, "asdf", "ASDF", "asDF", "ASdF")]
    [DataRow(3, "asdf", "ASDF", "1234", "d1sf5d1f")]
    [DataRow(2, "asdf", "ASDF", "ásdf", "ÁSdF")] //a and á (accent) are different characters 
    public void DbDistinct_ShouldBeCaseInsensitive(int expectedCount, params string[] strs)
    {
        var distinctStuff = strs.DbDistinct();
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedCount, distinctStuff.Count());
    }
}
```

When I run the unit test, I get this exception before it even make it into the body of the test:

> Test method ExtensionsTests.DbDistinct_ShouldBeCaseInsensitive threw exception:
> System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action action)

Interestingly, when I look at the error for a test case where there is only a single string to be passed into the params array (like the     `[DataRow(1, "stuff")]` test case), I get a different error:

> Test method ExtensionsTests.DbDistinct_ShouldBeCaseInsensitive threw exception:
> System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.String[]'.
> at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
> at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
> at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action action)

It looks like the DataRow is ignoring the `params` part of the test method. How can I specify a variable number of test elements to be passed into my test method? My test project is .NET Framework 4.8 (C# 7.3). I get the same error in both Rider and VS2022, so I don't think this is IDE-related.

Comment: Your code has "DbDistinct_ShouldBeCaseInsensitive" but the exception mentions "DbDistinct_ShouldHandleDifferentPrimitiveTypes". Are you sure you're looking at the right test?

Comment: Copied the wrong error message. There are multiple functions inside the class, but it's the same error. I'ved also added another error message.

Comment: Does it need to be `[DataTestMethod]` rather than `[TestMethod]` ?

Comment: No luck with that attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cause of the Exception

I think figured out why I ran into the Parameter mismatch or the invalid casting issues. The best guess I found based on a [linked article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130806-00/?p=3603) on [another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54296734/4320665):

The `DataRow` attribute has a constructor that doesn't play well with arrays because the constructor itself accepts `params Object[]`. This means that if you have an array whose type could fill the role of `Object[]`, the compiler prefers matching your array directly instead of expanding it as part of a `params` array.

The suggested solution to explicitly wrap things properly (with a collection initializer) is not compatible with Attributes because everything in an Attribute must be a compile-time constant (and therefore initializers and `new` don't work).

### My Solution: use `[DynamicData]`

I ended up side-stepping this issue by using a [DynamicData test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-create-a-data-driven-unit-test?view=vs-2022#member-data-driven-test). I defined a static property that generates my test cases. Each test case is defined as an `object[]`, whose elements are injected as parameters in my test method (in order). I made each test case be an expected value (`int`) and the test data (`string[]`):

```cs
public static IEnumerable<object[]> CaseInsensitiveTestCases
{
    get
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new object[] { 1, new string[] { "" } },
            new object[] { 1, new string[] { "stuff" } },
            new object[] { 1, new string[] { "asdf", "ASDF", "asDF", "ASdF" } },
            new object[] { 3, new string[] { "asdf", "ASDF", "1234", "d1sf5d1f" } },
            new object[] { 2, new string[] { "asdf", "ASDF", "ásdf", "ÁSdF" } }, //a and á (accent) are different characters 
        };
    }
}
```

Then I just used `[DynamicData]` attribute on my unit test method:

```cs
[TestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(CaseInsensitiveTestCases))]
public void DbDistinct_ShouldBeCaseInsensitive(int expectedCount, string[] strs)
{
    var distinctStuff = strs.DbDistinct();
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedCount, distinctStuff.Count());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to change test method parameters to int, string, and then separate params collection? It's a workaround but should do the trick. Off course you will need to compose input for method being tested.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Still the same parameter mismatch.