# String.Format derived from string "{0} (Length required 20)"

Tags: c#, string.format

I am receiving a string from a web api that is already in a String.Format like format.
Recieved string could be:

```
"{0} (Length required 20)"
"{0} {1} (Length required 20)(Mandatory)"
```

Is it possible to create a equal to

```
String.Format("{0}","Length required 20");
String.Format("{0} {1}","Length required 20","Mandatory");
```

From these strings

Comment: On a quick look there isn't a built in functionality for this (disappointingly) however it should be relatively easy to pull out the arguments with a regex.

Comment: It is not clear from your question what the actual _specification_ here is, never mind what _specifically_ you need help with. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. _"Is it possible?"_ is not a legitimate question. Are you trying to generate _code_ from the input string (exactly what you show above)? Or just break the input string into the string objects you want to pass to `string.Format()`? If the latter, what have you tried so far, what did that code code, how was that different from what you wanted, and what part do you need help with?

Comment: I also wonder about the web API itself. It seems remarkably silly to me for an API to return strings that look like that. What is the point of the format specifiers at all? The client code is going to have the manipulate the strings in some way anyway, and implied in your question is that the client is expected to format the string exactly as the API dictates, so why not just send the _formatted_ string back? Barring that, why not just delimit the individual string args, even with the parentheses shown here, and let the client reformat the strings however they like?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Well i was looking for a best practice on how to handle strings which are of this "silly" format, and was hoping that someone had a simular challange before me and could help me along the way. I agree with you that Is it possible?, is not a good question. However, sometimes i find it hard to explain problems in computing using the correct terminology. I also agree why the hell would an API return strings that looks like this, but that was not apart of my question.

Comment: _"that was not apart of my question"_ -- true enough. That comment of mine was less about the quality of the question itself and more just trying to get some insight as to the nature of the API. But I admit it is not directly relevant to the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you. First you need this method to extract collections out of your string:

```cs
    public static MatchCollection GetMatchedCollections(string stringToSearch, string pattern)
    {
       var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
       return regex.Matches(stringToSearch);
    }
```

Then you need two regexes:

1. ({[0-9]+})+
2. (([a-zA-Z].*?))

So for the string `{0} {1} (Length required 20)(Mandatory)` each of the above will
be extracted as follows respectively into collections:

1. {0} {1}
2. (Length required 20)(Mandatory)

So to use the above method all you have to do is:

```cs
    var masterString = "{0} {1} (Length required 20)(Mandatory)";
    var curlyBracesGroups = GetMatchedCollections(masterString, @"(\{[0-9]+\})+");
    var bracketsGroups = GetMatchedCollections(masterString, @"(\([a-zA-Z].*?\))");
    
    var curlyBraceGroupStr = "";
    foreach(var curlyBraceGroup in curlyBracesGroups)
    {
       curlyBraceGroupStr += curlyBraceGroup + " ";
    }

    var bracketGroup1 = bracketsGroups[0].Value;
    var bracketGroup2 = bracketsGroups[1].Value;
```

This will result to:

1. curlyBraceGroupStr -----> {0} {1}
2. bracketGroup1  -----> (Length required 20)
3. bracketGroup2  -----> (Mandatory)

P.S: You will also need to write a method that can make a call to `String.Format("{0} {1}","Length required 20","Mandatory");` based on the number of args. Please note that the `String.Format` accepts parameters of type `params obj[]`. It should be easy to create your method that can make the right call to the `string.Format`. However, if you have any issues, please post a separate question for it as that really needs its own title. Something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350/how-to-pass-a-single-object-to-a-params-object).

**Edit: The following is the comment from the op**

I ended up using this code based on your solution:

```
 public string GetToolTipString(string validatorTooltip)
        {

            MatchCollection curlyBracesGroups = GetMatchedCollections(validatorTooltip, @"(\{[0-9]+\})+");
            MatchCollection bracketsGroups = GetMatchedCollections(validatorTooltip, @"(\([a-zA-Z].*?\))");

            string curlyBraceGroupStr = "";
            foreach (var curlyBraceGroup in curlyBracesGroups)
            {
                curlyBraceGroupStr += curlyBraceGroup + " ";
            }
            
            return String.Format(curlyBraceGroupStr,bracketsGroups.Cast<Match>().Select(m=>m.Value).ToArray());

        }
        private MatchCollection GetMatchedCollections(string stringToSearch, string pattern)
        {
            var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            return regex.Matches(stringToSearch);
        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex in C#;
You can extract the arguments using [Regex.Matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netcore-3.1) and the following regex.

`(\(.*?\))`

You can then use [Regex.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netcore-3.1) and this regex to identify what to replace

`\{[0-9]+\}`

And the resulting matches from the first regex (kept in order of match) to replace these placeholders

you can check your Regular expressions in this [regex checker](https://regex101.com/)
if you are not aware of regular expressions you can have a look here [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html).

**Note:** this will not work on strings that contain '(' or ')' in the text to be substituted for {no.}.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
When i run : string s2 = "{0} {1} (Length required 20) (Mandatory)"; 
var i2 = Regex.Match(s2, @"(\(.*?\))");

It only returns (Length required 20)